# "My company is closed on the first and third Wednesdays of the month" -- Wednesday? or Wednesdays?

Tags: grammatical-number

I have a hard time figuring out if I should plural days of the week in this situation.

My company is closed **every Tuesday** (or just "**Tuesday**"? or "**Tuesdays**"??) and the 1st and 3rd **Wednesday**... or **Wednesdays**??

I feel like I'm being thrown for a loop and can't get answers anywhere. Please help!

Comment: *Every* **always** takes the singular. In the second case, both work. They form the sentence structure in different ways. Relax!

Comment: Why the close vote?

Comment: Different ways as in? Would the meaning change at all? Thanks for your answer. I was in a bit of a rush when I posted this so my tone is much more hurried than it should have been!